# Storing User Input in a List and writing a loop to find a valid value from that list

Tags: python, python-3.5

New to coding...
i am a student and have been tasked with writing a code that asks the user to input a series of values that will i will store in a list and then to ask to input a value (continue this until user types done) and then to check to determine if it is found in the list of valid values.

I'm assuming this could be done with a while true loop to accomplish the input until 'done' is typed and i'm assuming a search using 'if' and 'in' would accomplish the second part.

I am struggling finding a while true using the list of input. i am using an integer input. what am i comparing the condition to if to continue the loop?

Any help is appreciated! The code below is what i wrote i test if i could store input in a list but the while true is where i'm struggling with what to compare.

```
while True:
    if list_of_inputs
list_of_inputs = input("Write numbers: ").split()
list_of_inputs = list(map(int , list_of_inputs))
print (list_of_inputs)
```

Comment: Fix the code to be syntactically correct atleast as we are not write the whole code for you.

Comment: you should read up on indentation in python if this is what you have. Unlike other languages, strict indentation rules are mandatory.

Comment: if i remove the top two lines they are syntactically correct because i receive output in a list of what the input is. i'm asking if a while loop is the way to accomplish the input until 'done' is typed then what would i compare the 'if' to be true?

Comment: Your program specification is a bit unclear. I _think_ you're saying that the program first reads in a line of values, and stores those values into a list, which is your "list of valid values". Then it goes into a loop, reading one value per line, printing out a message that says whether that value is in the list of valid values or not. When a value of "done" is read, the loop terminates. Is that correct?

Comment: i'm using python 3.5

Comment: @PM2Ring this is where i'm struggling with the concept of an inputted values storing a list. as a student, the instructional material and reading only covered how to material that was already in a list. the instructor is asking to write a code for user input that will store a list and loop it until 'done'' is typed. that would be best served with a while loop correct?

Comment: `list_of_inputs = input("Write numbers: ").split()` _will_ create a list of strings. I'm happy to help you with this program, but I just need to know exactly what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: @PM2Ring the first portion is basically asking the user for a series of values that will be stored in a list until they type done. The second is to create a loop that would validate the list and continue to ask for a valid value until the user successfully input a value that can be found in the list. That second part would be a while loop i'm assuming as well with the if in function. I chose the user to just input integers thinking that would be easier than other values.

Comment: Ok. That's kind of the reverse of what I thought you wanted. :) And actually, it's easier to do this with strings than with integers. Give me a couple of minutes...

Comment: That's pretty easy to do.

Comment: @Abhishakegupta Yes, it is... when you know how. :) So change your old answer and undelete it.

Comment: I change my old answer buddy! please check and I thank you for clearing describing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that does what you described in the comments.

We use two `while` loops. The first one gets lines of input, one by one, and adds them to the `list_of_inputs`. If a line consisting of the string "done" is read we break out of the loop, and we *don't* add "done" to the list.

The second loop gets lines of input and tests whether or not they are present in `list_of_inputs`, printing an appropriate message. If the user inputs a line that *is* present in `list_of_inputs` we break out of the loop and the program ends.

```
print('Please enter values for the list, one value per line')
print('Enter "done" (without the quotes) to end the list')

list_of_inputs = []
while True:
    s = input('value: ')
    if s == 'done':
        break
    list_of_inputs.append(s)

print('Here is the list:')
print(list_of_inputs)

while True:
    s = input('Please enter a test value: ')
    if s in list_of_inputs:
        print('Yes!', repr(s), 'is in the list')
        break
    else:
        print('No', repr(s), 'is NOT in the list')
```

**test run**

```
Please enter values for the list, one value per line
Enter "done" (without the quotes) to end the list
value: abc def
value: ghi
value: jkl
value: done
Here is the list:
['abc def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
Please enter a test value: def
No 'def' is NOT in the list
Please enter a test value: ghij
No 'ghij' is NOT in the list
Please enter a test value: jkl
Yes! 'jkl' is in the list
```

Comment: Just for a better understanding... In my work outside i never created a variable 'list_of_inputs' so in what i was writing i was never able to compare that variable inside the loop. I think i understand what i was missing now!! I am only a student a miss the most simple things  for what seems the easiest assignments! Appreciate your help greatly @PM 2Ring!!

Comment: Apologies. I stumbled upon this sit while researching. I haven't fully understood all of the details of the site yet. I was thinking it was adding a reputation to the person for assistance. What does the repr module do? Again, appreciate all the help!!

Comment: @GregHarris The [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) function gets the representation of an object. For a string object, it returns the string with quote marks around it, like what you'd type into a Python program to create the string. See [Fancier Output Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) in the official Python tutorial.

Comment: @GregHarris You can only accept one answer (giving it the green check mark). But now that you have more than 15 points of reputation you can upvote _any_ good answers that you see on the site, not just answers to questions that you ask. See the [Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) help page for more details on the various privileges available.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x

```
list_of_inputs = list()
while True:
    var = input("Enter Number or type 'done' to exit :")
    if var.lower() == 'done':
        print(" Your inputs are: ",list_of_inputs)
        exit()
    else:
        list_of_inputs.append(int(var))
```

Make sure indentation is proper in python codes.